# xcode and iphone 6s update. Install sdk for ios 12. React native project broken

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, compilation

After upgrading iPhone to the iOS 12 and updating xcode, download SDK for ios 12 My project on react native can't build anymore.
I get a lot of different errors, for example:

`build input file cannot be found: 
'node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/libfishhook.a'`,

`Command CompileC failed with a nonzero exit code`

In addition, errors occur with the `third-party` folder

Several times already rebuilt the project, but it's not working

Comment: Hey @Zimovik007, were you able to see what was happening here, i'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove and add again libfishhook.a from Xcode and the path issue will resolve.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUpAW.png)